# Is it possible to re-order the node.js event loop?

Tags: javascript, node.js

In nodeJS, I know that if I dump a bunch of big callbacks on some asynchronous calls, they'll all be put in the event loop and eventually resolved. I'm pretty sure, based on the [MDN description of the event loop,](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/EventLoop) that this is generally done in a FIFO manner.

On an application I'm working on, I dump a bunch of asynchronous calls that manipulate a database based on some web scraping requests every 30 minutes. I don't really care if these take a minute or two to get through, since I'm only calling them every 30 minutes and the volume of these calls won't change.

However, if a user makes a `GET` request to the server during that two minutes, I'd rather have them not hit lag while the server finishes up processing all of the web scraping. Is there a way to fast-track these user requests to the front of the event queue?

Comment: why can't you run three loops - one for your scraping and one for GET requests (and the main one handling the incoming requests and routing accordingly)?

Comment: Would that require running multiple servers, or is there a way for a single server to create multiple event loops?

Comment: as per the answer provided below - make sure you understand how async works per event loop.  If you wish to run multiple event loops, you need to spawn multiple servers (nodejs processes) but only do that if you need to.  If you have async jobs running in one process, it should not impact your GET request (proved the scraping jobs really are async)

Comment: I re-read your question - you can do this in one event loop/server.  Simply make sure your scraping requests are async - that's it

Answer (score 3):

I think you have a misunderstanding here: it's not the asynchronous call that's being "put in the event loop and eventually resolved."  Rather the asynchronous call works in the background (while other events such as your GET request are processed in the event loop) and when a result comes back, this result together with the callback is put into the event loop.

So the GET request that comes in is served immediately anyway and there should be no need to fast-track it.